# Coefficient name not matching in R

Tags: r, survey, matching

I'm sure this is a simple question, but my rudimentary understanding of R is holding me back.  It probably has to do with a character string not being equivalent to the name of a variable...

I'm trying to run an interaction with contrasts using the survey package.

se_race4 is a factor variable that has 4 categories: "1) Non-Hispanic White", "2) Black", "3) Hispanic", "4) Other"

I run the model like so:

```
mod1 <- lm(sysbp ~ pmper10*se_race4 + age_baseline, data=mydata)
```

Then I look at some contrasts:

```
svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1)
```

The following commands work:

```
svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1,"pmper10:se_race42) Black"=1))
svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1,"pmper10:se_race43) Hispanic"=1))
svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1,"pmper10:se_race44) Other"=1))
```

But this does not (even though 'z' looks just like the above strings):

```
for(z in grep("pmper10:se_race4",names(coef(mod1)),value=TRUE)) {
    svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1, z=1))
}
```

R gives me the error:

```
Error in match.names(names(coef(stat)), contrasts) : names not matched
```

What am I missing?

Edit:
Results of `names(coef(mod1))`:

```
[1] "(Intercept)"                 "pmper10"                    
[3] "se_race42) Black"            "se_race43) Hispanic"        
[5] "se_race44) Other"            "age_baseline"               
[7] "pmper10:se_race42) Black"    "pmper10:se_race43) Hispanic"
[9] "pmper10:se_race44) Other"
```

Results of `names(c("pmper10"=1, z=1))`

```
 [1] "pmper10" "z"
```

Result of `z`

```
[1] "pmper10:se_race44) Other"
```

That doesn't look right!  How do I get "z" to turn into the value of z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error tells you that vector `contrasts` should match the vector `names(coef(stat))`, and it's not matching.

If you look on `svycontrast` help:

```
svycontrast(stat, contrasts, ...)
```

`stats` is your `mod1` and `contrasts` is the vector `c("pmper10"=1, z=1)`.

Type `names(coef(mod1))` and `names(c("pmper10"=1, z=1))`, to see where the error is.

You should replace your `for` command by:

```
sapply(grep("pmper10:se_race4",names(coef(mod1)),value=TRUE), function(z) {
    svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1, paste(z)=1))
})
```

EDIT:

It's not the most elegant solution but seems to work:

```
sapply(grep("pmper10:se_race4",names(coef(mod1)),value=TRUE), function(z) {
    contrasts <- c(1,1)
    names(contrasts) <- c("pmper10",z)
    svycontrast(mod1,contrasts)
})
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I get z to match? That is, how do I put the character string that z represents into the vector instead of just the letter z?

Comment: Could you paste here the result of `names(coef(mod))`? It would be helpful to understand what your `grep` command is doing. But possibly you could substitute `z` for `paste(z)`, although I haven't seen it, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe you should use the `paste(x)` function, that places it its place the string `x`. Try `svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1, paste(z)=1))`. EDIT: I'm editing my answer with a more complete answer.

Comment: Paste doesn't seem to work -- I get `Error: unexpected '=' in " svycontrast(mod1,c("pmper10"=1, paste(z)="` I'll try your method above.

Comment: Indeed my answer was wrong. The last edit gives the correct code.